# Data transfer from Microcontroller to computer

Tags: microcontroller, communication, computers, interface, peripheral

I'm looking for a good link to data from Microcontroller to computer.
I do not know what kind of communications is suitable for me.

I need a link which has a bit rate more than 50 Mbit/sec. and also it should be good enough reliable.

Moreover, I have not chosen the uC yet.
What about these choices?

1-(uC side) USB to USB (PC side)

2-(uC side) SPI to USB (PC side)

3-(uC side) ethernet to ethernet (PC side)

Data is in fact received from a 16 channel ADC with a rate of 100 K.
Data is processed in the uC and then would be sent continuously to PC.

Comment: You'll be lucky to find a USB to UART which will give you 50Mbit/s. What is the data? You could use high speed USB, there is enough bandwidth, or ethernet.

Comment: Well UART would not be enough for this speed. An MCU supporting USB 2.0 is OK, or you can go with Ethernet.

Comment: @BenceKaulics Thanks to the ambiguity of USB, it would need to be USB 2.0 high speed, not full speed to get that data rate

Comment: There are several things to consider here even allowing for the basic speed of Ethernet or USB which, on the face of it, seem the likeliest options.

The thing I always think that is of interest with things like this is even if you achieve 50M, what embedded micro will cope with processing 6.25million bytes of data per second? To use Ethernet or USB you'll need likely need a fairly processor intensive stack and, probably an OS and you'll end up needing a fairly powerful micro.

Cont below...

Comment: ...You could use raw Ethernet (rather than something like TCP or UDP/IP - I've seen that done successfully, but then it potentially makes things harder at the PC end because you're not just opening a standard port and having data pop out). 

One of the unknowns here is that we don't know how much data you need to process or what you're doing with it.  Will there be a continuous stream of data at 50M or bursts for example? One thing we can say is that USB to UART will not hack it!

Comment: That data rate is child's play but you are missing the important context in your question that explains what is generating the data and how the data is being processed when received. Without that information, there is no way of telling that this is a serious requirement. Please add some context because I don't want to waste my time.

Comment: can you do any kind of compression on the data? Cutting unnecessary padding could give you a bit of breathing room

Comment: USB, yes. UART, no. Your options are basically USB or Ethernet.

Comment: Some information about the data is added.

Comment: 16000*16*12 =~ 3 Mbits/s.  Can you post the ADC reference please? Can it really read all 16 channels simultaneously, or does it just have 16 multiplexed inputs? And can you really use >12 bits /Sa?  My proper oscilloscope only uses 8 bits /Sa.

Comment: @Paul Uszak any STM32 can do much more readings / sec. Usually it is max 2.4MSPS so he can read 16 channels x 3 ADC converters in one micro. so it gives easy 450k full 16 channel reads / second. Now I work on F303 ($3.0 micro) which has 3x 5MSPS ADC converters :). 100k 16 channel reads / sec is nothing

Answer (score 3):

When you're pushing that amounts of data through a microcontroller, you surely want to offload as much as you can to DMA. If data acquisition and transferring can be done in chunks of e.g. 256 or 512 samples it severely cuts down on CPU overhead.

An UART is pretty much out of the question. Even the fastest Baud rates some microcontrollers will manage is only half of the bitrate you need.

Ethernet is good starting point, but there are still some decisions to be made. Does the data transfer need to be lossless?

If some data loss is allowed then going for UDP is acceptable. UDP requires no handshaking, little CRC calculations and frames are almost as simple to setup as "raw" ethernet.

A 100MHz+ cortex m4 can saturate it's (internal!) 100MBits ethernet controller without much problems, if it's designed well.

If you need a TCP connection then things become much more complicated. Especially because TCP can potentially require a lot of buffer memory if the connection for whatever reason stalls momentarily. For that reason TCP performance can vary drastically depending which software stack you use, but from my experience 50Mbits is asking a lot.

You could potentially go for USB2.0 480Mbit/s using the microcontrollers onboard peripheral. However, USB stacks are quite fiddly to get working and if you're new to that I would advice against such a solution.

You could look into perhaps using an USB2.0 HS chipset like the FT232HQ. The asynchronous 245 FIFO interface allows external clocking and transfers over a parallel bus. The datasheet quotes up to 8Mbytes/sec transfer speed, which sounds like it is enough. However I do not know how easy that is to achieve and setup.

Answer (score 1):

Putting 50Mbit onto an Ethernet link is probably going to require either one of the "small computer" class boards, and even then you need to watch out for other bottlenecks. I have an iMX53 here where the sustained data rate for *random* DRAM access is only 128Mbit.

You've not said where the data is coming from? You might have to consider a FPGA-based solution using USB3, and that's very far from a beginner project.

Comment: That seems awfully slow for a 1 GHz Cortex A8, but maybe just goes to show what kind of power you really need.

Comment: Yes, I was hugely disappointed - it seems to be down to bus turnaround times, it takes several hundred DRAM cycles to set up a non-sequential read. Took ages to notice because cached reads were fast.

Comment: 50 Mbit/sec I think you meant.